# Raspberry Pi Zero W with OpenMoko CAN adapter

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W and a OpenMoko, Inc. Geschwister Schneider CAN adapter.  I watched this video on YouTube and removed the resistor:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DonsJ5cW55I&t=196s

I'm trying to set-up the system so that it boots up with the CAN adapter enabled and configured and is reliable and stays up, unfortunately what I see is that the system boots, the lights come on the adapter for a short period approx. 5 seconds then the lights go out except the power LED and the CAN0 adapter is no longer present.

From a Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS virtual machine, I connect to Raspberry Pi Zero W using SSH.

If I execute ip link I can see that can0 is not listed, although it is on start-up.

In /etc/modules I have:

```
i2c-dev
vhci-hcd
usbip-core
usbip-host
```

From ip link:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 disc no queue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default glen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default glen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Originally can0 was listed at 2.  From dmesg | grep can:

```
[.   4.136105] usb 1-1: Product: candleLight USB to CAN adapter
```

The release details of the OS on the Raspberry Pi Zero W:

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

In /etc/rc.local:

```
ip link set dev can0 type can bitrate 500000
ip link set dev can0 up
```

I also have in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto can0
iface can0 net manual
   pre-up ip link set dev $IFACE type can bitrate 500000
   pre-up ip link set dev $IFACE up
   up /sbin/ifonfig $IFACE up
   down /sbin/ifconfig $IFACE down
```

Adding the service /lib/systemd/system/usbip.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=usbip client
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/lib/linux-tools/$(uname -r)/usbip attach -r 192.168.0.10 -b $(/usr/lib/linux-tools/$(uname -r)/usbip list -r 192.168.0.10 | grep '10c4:8a2a' | cut -d: -f1)"
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "/usr/lib/linux-tools/$(uname -r)/usbip detach --port=$(/usr/lib/linux-tools/$(uname -r)/usbip port | grep '<Port in Use>' | sed -E 's/^Port ([0-9][0-9]).*/\1/')"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Once the above was added I then ran:

```
sudo systemctl --system daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable usbip.service
sudo systemctl start usbip.service
```

What I've tried to try and fix this:

1. Commenting out the 2 lines from rc.local, no difference, still comes on for 5 seconds then off, so I'm thinking lines in rc.local aren't required...
2. Commenting out the entries from /etc/network/interfaces, now the LED's don't light at all except the power LED.
3. After disabling everything then adding the service entry and commands to enable, rebooted and still can0 is not visible.
4. Disabled everything so configuration for can adapter, except it being plugged in.
   After performing each of the above, I shutdown and rebooted.
5. With all the modifications removed, no modifications above, so the system is just booted with no modifications except the USB CAN module is conneced.  After booting can0 is still not showing when executing ip link, it does immediately show if the USB connection is unplugged then reconnected.

After the results from 1 and 2 I've removed the content from /etc/rc.local and left just the settings in /etc/network/interfaces, the blue, green and red come on together for 5 seconds then the blue and green go out and can0 is no longer visible or accessible.